# How can I use tablesorter to sort multiple groups of rows separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I've seen similar questions about grouping rows in tablesorter but they are asking something slightly different than what I want. I would like a single table to have two groups of rows that get sorted separately. For example:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3  | <- this header never moves
|  A   |   1  |  1.5  |
|  J   |   3  |  2.7  | <- these three rows get sorted
|  X   |   2  |  1.2  |
|Totals|   6  |  5.4  | <- This totals the first group and never moves
| another header row  | <- this header never moves
|  B   |   5  |  5.0  |
|  L   |   3  |  8.2  | <- these three rows get sorted
|  N   |   7  |  3.3  |
|Totals|  15  | 16.5  | <- This totals the second group and never moves
```

This is sorted by col1. If I click on "col2", the top three rows should be A, X, J and the second three should be L, B, N. I'm sure this is possible but how can I get tablesorter to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) you can add multiple tbodies, and each will sort separately from the others. As for the total and extra header, also add these to separate `tbody` elements.

```
<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody><tr><!-- data --></tr></tbody>
  <tbody><tr><th>Totals</th><!-- ... --></tr></tbody>
  <tbody class="fake-header">
    <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody><tr><!-- more data --></tr></tbody>
  <tbody><tr><th>Totals</th><!-- ... --></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

No additional initialization is needed:

```
$(function() {
  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra']
  });
});
```

---

I set up [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4f3kwrzj/6/) which includes the math widget to calculate the row totals automatically for you. The only changes needed are in the total row:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Totals</th>
    <th data-math="above-sum"></th>
    <th data-math="above-sum"></th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And include the widget, and output mask in the initialization:

```
$(function() {
  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'math'],
    widgetOptions: {
      math_mask: '#,###.#'
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I was missing the fake-header bit. But the math stuff is not working for me. See https://jsfiddle.net/gperrow/n1fxujvo/15/. Also, is there a way to NOT sort the Rank column?

Comment: Include the widget code (https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/widgets/widget-math.js) - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/21v34u76/).

Comment: I also had to add another `<tbody></tbody>` around the header... to stop sort on the rank column, add a `sorter-false` class to the `<th>`.

Comment: The sorter-false class means that I can't sort using that column, which is fine, but I don't want that column to be sorted at all, i.e. regardless of how the rows are sorted, the top column should always be 1, the next one 2, and so on.